# Python Tornado – how can I fix 'URLhandler takes exactly X arguments' error?

Tags: python, tornado

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
ERROR:root:Exception in callback <tornado.stack_context._StackContextWrapper object at 0x1017d4470>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/ioloop.py", line  421, in _run_callback
    callback()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/iostream.py", line 311, in wrapper
    callback(*args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/httpserver.py", line 268, in _on_headers
    self.request_callback(self._request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1395, in __call__
    handler = spec.handler_class(self, request, **spec.kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

And here is the code:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = "Welcome!"

    def get(self):
        self.render("index.html", title=self.title)
```

I've simplified the code down to the above, and I am baffled as to why this is producing that error. I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea what (3 Arguments passed???...uhmm?)

Note: the `title` variable is merely the `<title>{{ title }}</title>` in my index.html template.

I am running Python 2.7.3, in 32 Bit version in order to work with Mysqldb-Python. As you can see, my Tornado version is 2.4.1. I am also running on OSX Lion (if that makes any difference...) Maybe a compatibility issue that is ultimately producing this error?

All help is appreciated in debugging this. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Princess of the Universe is right, but maybe this needs a bit of elaboration.

Tornado is going to call `__init__` on `RequestHandler` subclasses with the parameters `application, request, **kwargs`, so you need to allow for that.

You can do this:

```
def __init__(self, application, request, **kwargs):
    self.title = "Welcome!"
    super(IndexHandler, self).__init__(application, request, **kwargs)
```

Which means your `IndexHandler` class is now initialized with the same signature as the parent class.

However, I would favour the `initialize` method, which Tornado provides for this purpose:

```
def initialize(self):
    self.title = "Welcome!"
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I am just learning Tornado and this made complete sense to me. Very helpful.

Comment: Tornado makes no public documentation about `RequestHandler.__init__`, and therefore no backwards compatibility contract. I would consider the `initialize` the only valid approach, for now at least.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding

```
__init__()
```

in an inappropriate way.

See

http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/web.html

The signature is

```
class tornado.web.RequestHandler(application, request, **kwargs)[source]
```

It is clear that you have to provide the same API for the constructor of the derived class.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a little on what you mean when you say "you have to provide the same API for the constructor of the derived class"? For instance, how would I go about properly "overriding" `__init__`?

Comment: You have a significant lack in understanding programming and reading answers.  Your __init__() must provide the same parameter list as the __init__() of the base class which is clearly (application, request, **kwargs)

Comment: I apologize for not quite grasping the basics of Tornado yet, as I have just started to learn it; however, your answer, in conjunction with Cole's, now makes sense to me. Thank you.

Comment: This is a dead link.