# Tornado/Python: Why I can't reset variables inside a Class

Tags: python, class, variables, tornado

A simpilified code is as follow:

```
....

class indexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    a=[]

    def callback(self,response):
        #Do some other things, like write into database
        self.a=[]


    def get(self):
        print self.a
        self.a.append('abc')

        client=tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        client.fetch('http://google.com',self.callback)

        self.write('OK')
        ....
```

When I visit the page first time, the shell shows 
`[]`.
after page reload, it shows `['abc']`, reload once more then it shows `['abc','abc']` and so on.

Why the `a` wouldn't reset?

Comment: Because `a` is not an instance attribute, but a *class* attribute. It is shared among all instances.

Comment: Looking for the canonical question to link you to because this is being asked *all the time*. I hesitate to link you to ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941) though.

Comment: there are two variables. the former one is the class variable a (accessable using indexHandler.a), the other is the instance variable (accessable using self.a). both have nothing in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks both Martijn and mkind!
You all are right, I used `__init__` and it solves the problem.

Substitute `a=[]` with

```
def initialize(self):
    self.a=[]
```

would fix the problem.

Note that `def __init__(self)` alone does not work, Tornado provides the `initialize` function to substitute it. Read here: [python/tornado – Why am I getting this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907489/python-tornado-why-am-i-getting-this-error)